# Kafka-Streams - Filtering GlobalKTable before Joining

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

could you please give me an advice regarding the approach to the following problem. I have two topics, one with a static content and the second with a stream of data. The task is to join the data, which would be easy in a normal case. I would read the static content as a GlobalKTable and the dynamic content as KStream and simply join them. The problem is that the lookup data exist in multiple versions in the same topic. The "versions" are identified by a field "validFrom". So the data of the stream needs to be joined with the lookup data of a corresponding version according their timestamp. Is there a way to filter the data within a GlobalKTable?

Best regards
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply a filter operation on `GlobalKTable` itself but you could try to test the version of the records in the `ValueJoiner` and set the values of the join result records that do not pass the test to `null`. After the join, you can apply a filter that filters out all records that have a value that is `null`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bruno. It sounds promissing. I’ll try it out tomorrow and let you know, if it was successful.

Comment: I have tried this apprach, but I have the following problem: If I perform a leftJoin (KStream-GlobalKTable) with e.g. 3 identical keys on the right side to a certain key on the left side, than I would expect to get 3 entries fo that key, but I get only one entry. That means that the result gets exactly the same number of entries as the left side of the input data, although on the right side each key exists 3 times. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: You cannot have three identical keys on the right side. A `GlobalKTable` has table semantics. All records with the same key are updates on that key, ie, the first record with key `k` would be inserted into the table, the second record with key `k` would overwrite the value of the first record with its own value and the third record with key `k` would overwrite the value again. This is like an UPSERT in SQL.

Comment: Bruno, thank you for explanation. It explains the behavior completely!